# Jupyter notebook does not show C++ output (cout)

Tags: python, c++, jupyter-notebook

I am using a Jupyter Notebook as python interface to a C++ code. If I launch the same python code with

$ python mycode.py

I can see in the Terminal all the "std::cout" statements of the C++ code, but if I execute the Jupyter Notebook block all the "cout" are not displayed.

Do you know if and how I can see the standard output stream on Jupyter Notebooks?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a basic example where one can replicate the behavior?  Are you using C++ kernel in Jupyter notebook?, your description of the problem is too vague.

Comment: It is not straightforward to reproduce the behavior because it would be necessary to install various libraries (see [this link](http://nest-simulator.org)).
To better define the problem: I do not have the C++ kernel in Jupyter, because I only execute Python code that interfaces with the executable already compiled (the source code of the executable in C++).
I hope this clarifies a little the problem.

Comment: You scenario is very vague, can you elaborate more what do you mean by "python interface to c++ code"?, Can you kindly post an example preferably with a sample code to help you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is a known issue. When writing Python, most objects write the the `sys.stdout`/`sys.stderr` object, provides hooks to intercept. Most compiles library don't bother with trying to write to `sys.stdin`/`sys.stdout`, they just open the file descriptor and write to it, and you can't intercept that. Most of the time its something that could be fix in the underlying library, but not a lot of people bother to bug-report it.

You'll see your c++ output in the terminal where you started your notebooks. There are ideas on how to "fix" that, but it's non-trivial.

Note, you can reproduce by directly writing the filedescriptor `1`, "blah" will appear on the terminal where the notebook was started:

```
import os
os.write(1, 'blah\n'.encode())
```

My Terminal:

```
[I 12:13:51.703 LabApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 5cf9f732-5a0e-417d-8b66-bc50d3cbbe80
blah
[I 12:15:51.633 LabApp] Saving file at /Untilted1.ipynb
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I looked for it before asking, but I did not find answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your program with subprocess.check_output() you can get the C++ output to be displayed in the jupyter notebook.

example:

```
a = subprocess.check_output("./your_program")
print(a)
```

Comment: this only works for external executables, not for cython or other c++ embedded in the notebook

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`wurlitzer`](https://github.com/minrk/wurlitzer) package to capture C-level stdout / stderr and redirect it to IPython.

For example, include the following code blocks in your Jupyter notebook:

```py
%load_ext Cython
%load_ext wurlitzer
```

```py
%%cython
from libc.stdio cimport printf
def test():
    printf('abc')
```

```py
test()
# prints "abc"
```